# Gateway IP address lookup via ping

Tags: dns, ip

Trying to wrap my head around something that should be fairly easy to code.
The idea is to create a domain name and when the domain is used in a ping lookup the response would be your local (gateway router) IP address (IP4 and 6).

So when the ping of the domain was sent to the DNS server (web host) The Request packet would be pulled (containing the original IP requesting it) and returned back with Your own Gateway IP. Of course it would be masked.

Basically for easy lookups.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to write a DNS server that always returns the caller's public IP address.

That won't work, because DNS lookups go through one or more [recursive DNS servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Recursive_and_caching_name_server) (wuch as ISP DNS servers, OpenDNS, or Google's 8.8.8.8).

Your authoritative server does not know about the client that originally requested the domain name.